# css position absolute menu top

Tags: html, css

I am trying add notification icon, but is overflow text and dont on left.

Here is my code (run the snippet to see the result):

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.dropdown:hover {
    color: #e1a900;
}
.dropdown-content {
    background-color: #333333;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 180px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 64px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
    transition:color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #cc9900;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
.bellimg {
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.bellnumbers {
    font-size:12px;
    background-color:red;
    width:16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
}
.bell {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 48px;
    height: 42px;
    left: 30;
    position: absolute;
}
.notificationicon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
/********************************
* Menu Styles      *
*********************************/
#menu {
 height: 64px;
 width: 450px;
}
#menu ul,#menu li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
#menu li {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
}
#menu li a {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 -o-transition: color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
 -ms-transition: color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
 -moz-transition: color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
 -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
 transition: color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
}
#menu a {
 display: block;
 line-height: 35px;
 padding: 14px 10px 14px 5px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
#menu li:hover > a,#menu li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #e1a900;
}
#menu input {
 display: none;
 margin: 0 0;
 padding: 0 0;
 width: 80px;
 height: 35px;
 opacity: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#menu label {
 display: none;
 width: 35px;
 height: 36px;
 line-height: 36px;
 text-align: center;
}
#menu label span {
 font-size: 13px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 35px;
}
#menu ul.menus {
 /*background sub menus*/
 height: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 180px;
 background-color: #333333;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
 display: none;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 border-top: none;
 color: #fff;
}
#menu ul.menus a {
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0px;
}
#menu ul.menus li {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 text-transform: none;
}
#menu li:hover ul.menus {
 display: block;
 border-top: 2px solid red; 
 border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
#menu a.prett {
 padding: 14px 19px 14px 5px;
}
#menu li:hover > a.prett,#menu a.prett:hover {
 /*DropDown list background color*/
 background: #e1a900;
 color: #fff;
}
#menu a.prett::after {
 content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-width: 6px 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #eee transparent transparent transparent;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 right: 4px;
}
#menu ul.menus a:hover {
 /*Dropdown menu background color*/
 background: #e1a900;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
 #menu {width: 150px;}
 
 #menu a {padding: 0px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
 #menu a.prett {padding: 0px;}
 #menu a.prett::after {top: 15px;right: 4px;}
 
 
 #menu{position:relative;margin-top:0;}
 #menu ul{background-color: #333333;position:absolute;top:100%;right:0;left:0;z-index:3;height:auto;display:none;}
 #menu ul.menus{width:100%;position:static;border:none; border-top: 2px solid red; border-bottom: 2px solid red;}
 #menu li{display:block;float:none;width:auto;text-align:left}
 #menu li a{color:#fff}
 #menu li a:hover{color:#333}
 #menu li:hover{background:#e1a900;color:#fff;}
 #menu li:hover > a.prett,#menu a.prett:hover{background:#BABABA;color:#333;}
 #menu ul.menus a{background-color: #4d4d4d;}
 #menu ul.menus a:hover{background:#e1a900;}
 #menu input,#menu label{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:block;margin-top: 15px;}
 #menu input{z-index:4}
 #menu input:checked + label{color:#e1a900; background-color: #404040;}
 #menu input:checked ~ ul{display:block;}
}
.menu_head {
 width: 100%;
 height: 64px;
 background-color: #000;
 background-image: url("../images/menu.png");
 box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0, .8);
 background-position: top;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 color: #fff;
 z-index:1;
 font-weight: bold;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu_head'>
  <!-- MENU LEFT -->
  <nav id='menu' style='border: 1px solid #fff;'>
   <input type='checkbox'/>
   <label>&#8801;<span>MENU</span></label>
   <ul>
    <li><a href=''>Home</a></li>
    <li><a class='prett' href='' onclick='return false;'>Rules</a>
     <ul class='menus'>
      <li><a href='#'>Rules </a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class='prett' href='' onclick='return false;'>Suporte</a>
     <ul class='menus'>
      <li><a href='#'>Terms of Service</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
    <div class='notificationicon'>
<span class='bell'>
    <img class='bellimg' src='../images/notification.png'/>
    <span class='bellnumbers'>10</span>
</span>
<span class='dropdown'>
    <div style='float: right; line-height: 64px; margin-right:15px;'>Welcome asd asd asd asd x3G</div>
    <div class='dropdown-content'>
        <a href=''>PROFILE</a>
        <a href=''>TEAM</a>
        <a href=''> SETINGS</a>
        <a href=''>BALANCE</a>
        <a href=''> INBOX</a>
        <a href=''> LOG OUT</a>
    </div>
</span>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
  <div style='clear:both;'></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the *.bell* class you have defined the **left** property value without a unit, for example px (See image below for reference)

Simply add a unit like **px** or **%** and it should work:

```
.bell {
    left: 30px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @cesar.correchel please never answer off-topic questions. You will be able to comment on other people posts when you reach 50 reputation.